# Wich methods could I try to run a feature selection on 5k+ features?

Tags: python, machine-learning, feature-selection

I'm working on python, have a 10gb dataset with 5k features, want to do a FS to later train it with one or more of these: LightGBM, XGBoost, Google Automl.

I tryied min-max, Boruta (that gave me 2400 features, thats a lot I can force it to less, but, want to try another approach and see the interesection of features), wanted to try borutaShap but not luck making the multiprocess work so it's too slow to try.

I can shuffle and use a subset (currently im using the training subset for this process), but I thing I'm missing something.
I'm looking for some methods maybe I didn't stumble uppon to try, all the examples that I found concentrate in the handle of 10 features and they don't scale.
Have only continuous variables.

Any article, snippet, tool on how to approach this will be more than appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Try to apply a model and see which features are working for it. Say use a Random Forest and see feature importance and do the needful. To train this mini model you can use a subset of data stratified on your target. Also, remember that feature selection is important relative to the algorithm and as you are using boosting algorithms try to FE relative to them.

Comment: The features that reach production will affect the number of called APIs and more suseptible to infrastructure noise (in some cases), that's why I don't train a model with full features.
RandomForest is what Boruta uses by default to select most important features, it slash the variables in half, but there are still to much. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to manually select these feature using domain knowledge it could be beneficial to you (depending on the problem).

You can find some good basic "statistical" methods in scikit:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html

Perhaps you could apply some of them in combination, such as removing features with low variance and the Boruta method to "prune" your features further?

Other methods you could use would be to train a simple model (yet useful) that can handle a lot of features and then look at the feature importance. Then you could select a set number of the top features.

Maybe use permutation based feature importance:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/permutation_importance.html

and a simple decsion tree or a random forest with "shallow" depth?

Comment: Manually selected variables is the next step, but there are so many of them that will be very helpfull to make a prune before, to make, if necessary a clean when the quantity is maneagable and of course use this knowledge on future models